# Cordova: Ajax funciona no navegador mas não no aparelho Android

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, ajax, apache-cordova

Necessito fazer uma requisição ajax utilizando o Cordova no visual studio, e ajax através do JQuery. Quando faço o teste através do navegador funciona corretamente, mas quando faço teste Android ele retorna erro com stauts "0" e nenhuma mensagem. O que poderia ser?

```
function teste_login(cpf, password) {
var cpfSenha = { cpf: cpf, senha: password };
var retornoObj;

cpfSenha = JSON.stringify(cpfSenha);

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://url-arquivo.php',
    type: 'POST',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: cpfSenha,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (msgJson) {

       retornoObj = JSON.parse(msgJson.replace(/ +(?![\. }])/g, ''));

        if (retornoObj.sucesso == true) {             
            window.location.href = "principal.html";
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(xhr.responseText);
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isso pode variar, depende da versão do **HTML** que está no dispositivo, tente ver também se as **permissões** necessárias da aplicação Android para fazer este tipo de procedimento (que é uma requisição externa) estão adicionadas.